# socket.io chat add user name to disconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, message

I'm new to socket.io. I have been working on this message chat for a while. I was able to add usernames to the chat when a user logs in and submits a message but for the life of me I can't get it to read the users names when users disconnect. Maybe I've been working on this too long but the answer shouldn't be that hard since I have the usernames working on connect and submit.

This is what I have on the client side.

```
socket.on('connect', () => {
        // emiting to everybody  
        socket.emit('join', { room: room, name: name });    
      })
```

**name** holds the logged in username.

On the server side I have this.

```
socket.on('join', (data) => {    
    socket.join(data.room); 
    tech.in(data.room).emit('message', `${data.name} joined ${data.room} room!`);
})

socket.on('disconnect', (data) => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
    tech.emit('message', 'user disconnected' + data.name );
})
```

The connect works fine, when a user connects I get the user's name has joined the room but I get undefined for the disconnect "user disconnected undefined". Not recognizing the var. I'm guessing I need to emit it for disconnect on the client side? This seems like it should be easy but is giving me problems.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On server side, you can do like this:

```
let users = {}
io.of('/test').on('connection', (socket) => {
    
    socket.on('join', (data) => {
        socket.join(data.room);
        
        users[socket.id] = data;

        io.of('/test').to(data.room).emit('message', `${data.name} joined ${data.room} room!`);
    })
    
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        io.of('/test').emit('message', 'user disconnected ' + users[socket.id].name);
        delete users[socket.id];
    })
})
```

Since you are not storing your event payload, so I stored it in an object 'users'. You can also store it in cache

Also I would like to mention that **disconnect** event does't support arguments. You can refer from the link below.
https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/#socket-disconnect

Answer (score 0):

```
  io.use((socket: any, next: any) => {
     //you can do authentication in this middleware
     // you can also validate query data here => socket.handshake.query
     if (authenticated){
         socket.data.groupid = socket.handshake.query.groupid;
         next();
     }else{
         return new Error('Authentication error')
     }
  })
  .on('connection',socket:any) => {

       socket.join(socket.data.groupid, () => {
          // you can join the room from inside here
       });
     
       socket.on('disconnect', () => {
         //you can handle disconnect event here
       });
  })
```